# Conditional Distribution absolutely continuous w.r.t Lebesgue measure?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X,Y$ be integrable random variables.  Then the condition expectation of $Y$ given $X = x$ is defined as
$$
\mathrm E[Y \mid X=x] := \int_\Omega Y(\omega) \, P^X(\mathrm dw \mid x),
$$
where $P^X(\cdot \mid \cdot)$ is the regular conditional probability of $P$ given $X$.  Then using the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$, $P_{Y \mid X}(\cdot \mid \cdot)$, we can push forward this integral to the range of $Y$:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} y \, P_{Y \mid X}(\mathrm dy \mid x).
$$

Now, in [these notes](http://www.randomservices.org/random/expect/Conditional.html) they define the conditional expectation of $Y$ given $X = x$ as
$$
\mathrm E[Y \mid X=x] := \int_{\mathbb{R}} y \, h(y \mid x) \, \mathrm dy, \qquad (1)
$$
where $h(\cdot \mid x)$ is the conditional probability density function of $Y$ given $X = x$.

My question is, for (1) to make sense, are the authors assuming that $P_{Y \mid X}(\cdot \mid x) << \lambda$  where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$?  And then, are they assuming $h(\cdot \mid x) = \frac{\mathrm dP_{Y \mid X}(\cdot \mid x)}{\mathrm d\lambda}$?  If so, (1) would obviously allow us to compute the expectation using Riemann integration, but it seems like one would always need to check that $P_{Y \mid X}(\cdot \mid x) << \lambda$ before immediately jumping to (1).

Comment: Indeed (1) is restricted to the case when $P_{Y\mid X}(\ \mid x)\ll\lambda$ for every $x$. Not much more to add, except that I certainly would not take (1) as a definition.